# System.Timers.Timer thread query

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, service, timer, smtp

am attempting to write a system service which monitors what time it is. When it reaches a set time then it will trigger an email containing data from a database.

I have implemented the following code which creates a system.timers.timer object and adds a handler to the **elapsed** event. This then compares the specified time to the system clock using an if statemnt. If the statement is true then an email is generated

**Problem 1**
The if statement does not fire when it reaches the correct time. I am assuming this is because the system clock does not match exactly the time specified. Would it be possible to allow a range to ensure that the system clock will match the specified time

**Problem 2**
If i change the matching type on the if statement to "If now > Email Time" then the if statement runs. However it then runs the if statement every time the timer reaches the interval, which is every 100ms. If i understand correctly this will be running each instance of the event in a separate thread. Is there a way to limit it to one thread, that way it would would stop processing the timer events whilst in the middle of the IF statement

Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System
Imports System.Timers

Public Class Service1
    Dim MyTimer As New System.Timers.Timer()
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.

```
    Console.WriteLine("OnStart")


    AddHandler MyTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

    ' Set the Interval to 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds).
    MyTimer.Interval = 1000
    MyTimer.Enabled = True



End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    Console.WriteLine("OnStop")
    Timer1.Stop()

End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("OnTimerEvent!")

    Dim EmailTime As DateTime = #12:20:00 PM#


    If Now > EmailTime And Now < EmailTime Then
        Dim MyLog As New EventLog() ' create a new event log 
        ' Check if the the Event Log Exists 
        If Not Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("QEDService") Then
            Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("QEDService", "QEDService Log") ' Create Log 
        End If
        MyLog.Source = "MyService"
        ' Write to the Log 
        Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("QEDService Log", "This is log on " & _
        CStr(TimeOfDay), EventLogEntryType.Information)


        Try
            Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
            Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
            Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password")
            Smtp_Server.Port = 587
            Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
            Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

            e_mail = New MailMessage()
            e_mail.From = New MailAddress("This is a test message subject")
            e_mail.To.Add("alex@qedscaffolding.com")
            e_mail.Subject = "Email Sending"
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
            e_mail.Body = "This is a test message body"
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
            MsgBox("Mail Sent")

        Catch error_t As Exception
            MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
        End Try
    End If


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You'll need to think about `If Now > EmailTime And Now < EmailTime Then` for a while.  Using As New for the timer is also a grave mistake, you add yet another event handler every time you start the service.  Using MsgBox in a service is also very wrong, nobody can see it or click on OK.  Ask your team members for help, let them review your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is there any way you could demonstrate how you would implement the above. I have removed all message boxes and understand why they would not work. The "as new timer" is declared in the OnStart procedure which i would assume only runs one, please correct e if this is not true. Thankyou

Comment: Why do you have a recurring Timer for an event that you only want to do once?  Why not just have to Timer fire at EmailTime?

Comment: my understanding was that you needed the timer to continually evaluate the time. Without it nothing would constantly check what time it was. Could you elaborate with an example of implementation, cheers